# How to declare which methods can be applied to which objects

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, architecture

I'm writing a server application which functionality is called via RPC. Application has objects which can interact with each other.

Assume the following simplified example:

- A person can inspect and fix, and can be inspected;
- A car can brake, and can be inspected and be fixed.

Straightforward implementation **¹** (RPC is out of scope):

```
class Car(object):
    def __init__(self, broken=False):
        self.name = 'car'
        self.broken = broken

    def breaks(self):
        self.broken = True
        print 'Car broke'

    def inspected(self, by):
        if by.pro:
            if self.broken:
                print '{}: It\'s a broken car'.format(by.name)
            else:
                print '{}: It\'s a working car'.format(by.name)
        else:
            print '{}: It\'s a car'.format(by.name)

    def fixed(self, by):
        if not self.broken:
            print 'Car is not broken'
        else:
            self.broken = False
            print by.name, 'fixed the car'


class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name, pro=False):
        self.name = name
        self.pro = pro

    def inspect(self, target):
        target.inspected(by=self)

    def fix(self, target):
        target.fixed(by=self)

    def inspected(self, by):
        if self.pro:
            print '{}: {} is a pro'.format(by.name, self.name)
        else:
            print '{}: {} is not a pro'.format(by.name, self.name)
```

Create some objects:

```
>>> car = Car()
>>> john = Person('John', pro=True)
>>> bob = Person('Bob', pro=False)
```

Now user can interact with them **²**:

```
>>> car.breaks()
'Car broke'
>>> john.inspect(car)
"John: It's a broken car"
>>> john.fix(car)
'John fixed the car'
>>> bob.inspect(john)
'Bob: John is a pro'
```

The problem here, if we call `john.fix(bob)` then we will get `AttributeError: 'Person' object has no attribute 'fixed'`.

**So, what is a good and/or 'pythonic' way to declare/restrict which methods can be applied to which objects?**

So far I came up with the following ideas:

1. Make an bloated base (abstract) class which will have stubs for all possible methods and properties. The downside here is, as the project grows and new methods are added, it should be updated separately; and all child classes will have a lot of unrelated and unused stuff. Also, doesn't really solve the problem.
2. Wrap all calls with `try...except`. Doesn't look stable and 'pythonic', and doesn't solve the problem.
3. Manually specify which classes are supported by methods. Not maintainable as the project grows, and does not strictly tell which attributes target class must have.
4. Multiple inheritance. Fixes the problem with #3 when, while creating new `FixAllRobot` class with fix method, we might forget to add `pro` attribute needed for target's checks. Cons: `class Person(Inspecter, Fixer, ..., TwentyMoreOneFunctionHolder)` doesn't look trustworthy and readable. And we still need to check if action can be used on target.
5. Pretty much like #4, but inherit also target-side classes. Cons: Inheritance hell: `class Person(Inspecter, CanBeInspected, Fixer, ...,  FortyMoreOneFunctionHolder)`. Pros: Looks like a solution.

Notes:

1. About inspect and inspected (and other action pairs): There are some class dependent actions for both object and subject which must be made when action is called.
2. For now all objects of the same class are stored in their class dictionary with their id as key. Meta class keeps track of what classes were created. User is usually in control of only one object. When user sends RPC request (actually json-rpc) which may look like `{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 77, "method": "inspect", "params": {"target": "car", "id": 1}}`, `target` is resolved as target class and `id` as instance identifier. Some optional parameters might also be passed through `params` dict.

Sidenote: I am aware of QT signal-slot system and love it, but I think it's not the case.

Sidenote2: I'm stuck to python 2.7

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. What could a **restriction** ever actually do other than raise an exception? Python already does the right thing by raising an `AttributeError`, so there is no problem to solve. All you need to do is provide appropriate documentation for your APIs.

Comment: It's not about restriction in usage, it's more about designing its core the way it will be obvious what should be done to properly add new functionality, like zope.interface does.

Comment: The "problem" example you gave is specifically a restriction in usage - i.e. calling `john.fix` with the wrong argument type.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest going with the `try...except` method. EAFP ("Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission") is according to https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp considered pythonic. It also scales well, as the project grows.

Comment: My sense of beauty tells me that wrapping every method call with try...except doesn't look good. And specifying in documentation that every new method should also do so looks awful.